# How to list all events from a particular folder which are going on today? And email the list to users

Tags: email, event-handling, plone

I have a 4.0 instance of plone. I want to list events from a folder which are either starting from today or the date range (start date and end date) contains today's date.
I also need to send email to a group with these events listed in mail. I have added a Python Script at ZMI, which is working perfect. Only thing is that when I am sending mail, only one event detais are listed in the mail. I don't know how to iterate so that i will get full list. Please guide.

```
import datetime

folder_path = '/'.join(context.getPhysicalPath()) + '/events'

# Convert Date yyyy/mm/dd to dd month yyyy
now = DateTime().Date()
nowd = DateTime(now)

#dateList = [nowd10 - nowd10+margin]
#print dateList
#return printed

dt = nowd.strftime('%b %d,%Y')
now_date = DateTime(now)


query=context.portal_catalog(portal_type='Event',
                        start={'query': (nowd-10,nowd+1),
                        'range': 'min:max'})

results = context.portal_catalog(path={'query': folder_path, 'depth': 1})
folder_dict={}
for ev in results:
  if ev.portal_type == 'Event':
     loc = ev.location
     stdt = ev.start.Date()
     stdt = DateTime(stdt)
     endt = ev.end.Date()
     endt = DateTime(endt)
     if nowd - 10 <= stdt <= nowd:
        evobj = ev.getObject()
        mydict = {}
        mydict['absolute_url'] = evobj.absolute_url()
        mydict['StartDate'] = stdt
        mydict['EndDate'] = endt
        mydict['Location'] = loc
        msgbody = ""
        for y, z in evobj.getMetadataHeaders():
           mydict[y] = z
           msgbody = """
           Title: %(Title)s
           Start: %(StartDate)s
           End: %(EndDate)s
           Event Location: %(Location)s
           Link to Event page: %(absolute_url)s
           """ % mydict
        msgbody = msgbody + msgbody


# Send email
mFrom = "fromemail"
mTo = "to email"
mMsg = "Events for Today:"
mMsg += msgbody
mSubj = "Events  " + dt

context.MailHost.send(mMsg, mTo, mFrom, mSubj)
```

Comment: You have 2 catalog searches in your code, but the first one isn't used. Did u see that?

Comment: You seem to be having too many variables called `msgbody`, one for the overall total and one in the innermost loop.

Comment: Also, you can put the portal_type into the portal_catalog query. You can do that for the start and end date as well, although it's a bit trickier. That would speed this up a lot when you have many events.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a collection to get all events which contain today in their daterange and for the mail-sending you can use colective.contentrules.mailtotogroup. It is capable to send the body-text-field, too. If that's what you were looking for.